# Are .NET Core Runtime patches automatically applied via Microsoft Update?

Tags: .net-core, updates, windows-update

The .NET (Standard) framework receives automatic updates via the Windows Update service. Does .NET Core Runtime have the same/similar functionality? If I install a .NET Core Runtime and .NET Core application on a server should I be the one taking care to apply the latest minor patch?

My question is primarily focused on potential security issues which are then remedied by subsequent minor version update.

Comment: No, it doesn't. .NET Core isn't Windows specific

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the [currently supported versions](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core) of .NET 5, .NET Core 3.x and .NET Core 2.x can now receive automatic updates. [See the .NET Blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-updates-coming-to-microsoft-update) announcing this for more information.

It is in an opt-in service, so on a client OS you would need to enable *Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows*.

[image: Advanced options - receive updates for other MS products.]

On server OS the updates are managed via Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) or System Center Configuration Manager (SCCM). See the section [for IT administrators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-updates-coming-to-microsoft-update/#for-it-administrators) on the MS blog for detailed instructions.

Comment: this does NOT apply when you create an .net executable which includes the .net binaries themself.